# Add button with onclick event to each row in datatable in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, datatables-1.10

How to add a button with onClick for each row in Datatable in reactjs. Whenever I add the button and tried I'm getting a function not defined error. Is there any way to handle this or add the button?. I have added the Server-Side (Node JS) and Client-Side (React JS). Thanks in advance

Node JS Code

```
app.get("/students", (req, res) => {
    db.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users ;",
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({ err: err });
            }
            if (result.length > 0) {
                var results = [];
                result.forEach(function (row) {
                    results.push({
                        FIRST_NAME: row["FIRST_NAME"],
                        LAST_NAME: row["LAST_NAME"],
                        EMAIL: row["EMAIL"],
                        DOB: row["DOB"],
                        PARENT_NAME: row["PARENT_NAME"],
                        PARENT_CONTACT_NO: row["PARENT_CONTACT_NO"],
                        EDIT: "<a class='btn btn-info btn-sm' href=UpdateStudent?id=" + row["ID"] + "> EDIT </a> &nbsp; <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onClick='{()=>{this.setState({show:true})}}'> DELETE </button>"
                    })
                })
                res.send(results)
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "No data found, Please try again !!!" });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

React JS

````
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Axios from "axios";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables"
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
import BootBox from 'react-bootbox';

import $ from 'jquery';

class StudentsList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            students: [],
            loading: true,
            show: false
        };
    }

    showAlert = () => {
        alert('Yes is clicked');
    }

    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false })
    }

    async getStudentsData() {
        const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Students");
        this.setState({ loading: false, students: res.data });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getStudentsData().then(() => this.syncTable());
    }

    syncTable() {
        this.$el = $(this.el);
        this.$el.DataTable({
            data: this.state.students,
            columns: [
                { title: "First Name", data: "FIRST_NAME" },
                { title: "Last Name", data: "LAST_NAME" },
                { title: "Email Id", data: "EMAIL" },
                { title: "Date Of Birth", data: "DOB" },
                { title: "Parent Name", data: "PARENT_NAME" },
                { title: "Parent Contact No", data: "PARENT_CONTACT_NO" },
                { title: "Action", data: "EDIT" },
            ]
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="MainDiv">
                <div className="jumbotron text-center bg-sky">
                    <h3>Students List</h3>
                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    <table id="studentsList" className="display" ref={(el) => (this.el = el)}>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <BootBox
                    message="Do you want to Continue?"
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onYesClick={this.showAlert}
                    onNoClick={this.handleClose}
                    onClose={this.handleClose} />
            </div>
        );     
    }
}
export default StudentsList;```
````

Comment: In the constructor add this.handleClose.bind(this); then try it out

Comment: `<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onClick='{()=>{this.setState({show:true})}}'> DELETE </button>`

Should I change something in button

Comment: @miguelsolano, I tried adding `this.handleClose.bind(this);` inside constructor and also changed Button `<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onClick='{()=>{this.handleClose()}}'> DELETE </button>` didn't worked I mean function call is not hapenning.Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Change it from and arrow function to regular function.

Comment: @miguelsolano, I tried iike this `<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onClick='{this.handleClose}'> DELETE </button>` but didn't work. Can you show me how?.

Comment: handleClose = function() {

Comment: @miguelsolano Didn't work, `<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onClick='{this.handleClose}'> DELETE </button>`

`handleClose = function () {
        alert("Check")
        this.setState({ show: false })
    }`

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No Error, I think function call is not hapenning

Comment: Oooooo hahaha switch from onYesClick to onClick

Comment: Sorry it’s a bit early where I am from

Comment: I have added onClick only

Comment: onYesClick={this.shouldAlert} in the BootBox component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224327/discussion-between-sheik-sena-reddy-and-miguelsolano).

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing is that in the react application you use DataTables as a standalone Jquery based library.

React version of DataTables (react-data-table-component package) would have column properties:

```
format?: (row: T, rowIndex: number) => React.ReactNode;
cell?: (row: T, rowIndex: number, column: IDataTableColumn, id: string | number) => React.ReactNode;
```

either of which will allow you to custom render a button for each cell.

In the standalone version of DataTables there are [custom data renderers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) which may do the same.